# How can I access my Unity DI container?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, unity-container

I'm using Unity Mvc4 package, which has a bootstrap class (below) which runs on Application Start

How can I access my container, without using my dirty static property?

```
public static class Bootstrapper
    {
        public static IUnityContainer Container { get; set; }
        public static IUnityContainer Initialise()
        {
            Container = BuildUnityContainer();
            DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new UnityDependencyResolver(Container));
            return Container;
        }

        private static IUnityContainer BuildUnityContainer()
        {
            var container = new UnityContainer();
            // register all your components with the container here
            // it is NOT necessary to register your controllers

            // e.g. container.RegisterType<ITestService, TestService>();    
            RegisterTypes(container);
            RegisterInstances(container);
            return container;
        }

        public static void RegisterTypes(IUnityContainer container)
        {
            container.RegisterType<IDataAccessHelper, DataAccessHelper>();
        }

        public static void RegisterInstances(IUnityContainer container)
        {
            container.RegisterInstance<GlobalHelper>(new GlobalHelper());
        }

    }
```

Comment: My answer would be: you shouldn't, because it breaks the IoC pattern.  What are you trying to do, maybe there's a better way?

Comment: Ah, thank you! I see, so you register Singletons and it automatically resolves it? heh, sorry I'm very new to server-side dependency injection

Comment: There is no need for, because this is a singleton object. There will be only one instance of the unity container and that is why a static property is fine.

Comment: You should never expose the container to the public. Instead, read on the Composition Root. If you still have questions, come back again.